# which control touched

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

In below code how can i understand that which control touched?(imagine that exist button1,label1,.. on view)

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006785-CH3-SW8) property on the touch object. From the documentation:

> The value of the property is the view
>   object in which the touch originally
>   occurred.

Comment: What's the output of `NSLog(@"touch.view: %@", touch.view);`?

Comment: touch.view: <UIView: 0x592ed60; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x592ede0>>

Comment: From the Run menu in Xcode, choose Debug. Once the app is running, go back to Xcode and choose Console from the Run menu.

Comment: Do you have userInteractionEnabled set to YES on your subviews? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled